# How to install a Delphi Webservice ISAPI module on Apache 2.3

Tags: web-services, delphi, apache, soap, isapi

I have a webservice compiled into a ISAPI module (dll). I have Apache 2.3 correctly installed. How to install this DLL into apache?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It's Apache 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the info that I used to setup my delphi isapi dll with apache 2.2:
http://mc-computing.com/databases/Delphi/WebServers/WebServers.html

Basically you need to make the following modifications in the httpd.conf:
Uncomment the isapi_module:

```
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
```

and then at the end of the file add:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # This allows ISAPI dll's and CGI exe's (both are required for regular aliases)
    AddHandler isapi-isa .dll
    AddHandler cgi-script .exe

    Alias /isapi "d:/faxsrv/httpd"

    <Directory "d:/faxsrv/httpd">
        Options  ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

For this example config, to access your isapi, go to the address:

http://localhost/isapi/yourisapidll.dll

Comment: Hello! You got a +1 because i foud your information useful, but i really need to know how to setup a isapi dll. I'm using

LoadModule WebModule_Principal "D:/WebService.dll"

But I'm not sure about what to place on the "second parameter". WebModule_Principal is wrong, of course and I do not know what to put there.

Comment: I don't use anything like LoadModule WebModule_Principal. I just followed the instructions in that article... and my isapi dll worked from first try. I made some edits to the answer, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2):

I once published (with some help by David Moorehouse) updated headers for apache 2.2
but note that these aren't unicodified yet so they work only with Delphi 2007....

You can download them under:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2-25399-163963-2029/ApacheTwoHTTP.zip